# Why can't i see my JSON question in my text view?

Tags: java, android, json

For a feedback app, I need to display a different question with multiple posibility-answers a day, from a Json File that has an array of questions, the questions have to be randomly displayed on the screen, one a day. I loaded the file from Assets, everything works fine butt the question won't appear. Below is my Java Code, could someone help me?

```
    try {
            readJson();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void readJson() throws JSONException {
        String qaJSONString = loadFileFromAssets("QA.json");
        System.out.print(qaJSONString);


        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(qaJSONString);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("KalenderTag");

        JSONObject montag = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);


        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_View_result);
        //      Umfrage umfrage1 = new Umfrage(montagJSON.getString("Frage"));
          //      textView.setText(umfrage1.getFrage());

    }

    private String loadFileFromAssets(String filename) {
        String tContents = "";

        try {
            InputStream stream = getAssets().open(filename);

            int size = stream.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            stream.read(buffer);
            stream.close();
            tContents = new String(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Json could not be parsed to string!");
        }

        return tContents;
    }
```

Comment: check "System.out.print(qaJSONString);" prints in logcat?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: You should debug this method line by line then you can check what are stored in your variables. But.. maybe you got an exception in your comment lines.

Comment: now check you are getting "KalenderTag" and have atleast one object and also check for exception

Comment: @pratikvekariya i don`t quite understand your answer sorry....

Comment: @Olga-MariaBarbu i mean in your "qaJSONString" it is have "KalenderTag" array with atleast one length